# jQuery toggle class and change it on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have the following code in my JS file:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function (e) {
        var menu = e(".menu-container");
        var button = e(".menu-functions");
        e(window).scroll(function () {
                if (e(this)
                    .scrollTop() > 150) {
                    menu.addClass("f-nav");
                    button.addClass("collapse-expand");
                    button.addClass('collapse');
                } else {
                    menu.removeClass("f-nav");
                    button.removeClass("collapse");
                    button.removeClass("expand");
                    button.removeClass("collapse-expand");
                }
            });
        //problem area
        $('#menu-functions').click(function(){
            if(button.hasClass('collapse'))
            {
                button.addClass('expand');
                button.removeClass('collapse');
            }
            if(button.hasClass('expand'))
            {
                button.addClass('collapse');
                button.removeClass('expand');
            }
        });
});
```

Now I need to make it so that the part under the `// problem area` starts to work. I reckon there's a `toggleClass` in jQuery, right? Some advanced conditions could do the trick, however I'm still learning and I need some help. I also need to find a way to `animate()` the `.menu-container` div whether the button state is expand or collapse:

- If the button was clicked while it had the `expand` class

  - animate the menu from bottom to top with 98px;
- If the button was clicked while it had the `collapse` class

  - animate the menu from top to bottom with 98px.

**EDIT - JSFIDDLE:**
[jsfiddle.net/rcdhnh7L](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdhnh7L)

Comment: Jsfiddle for better understanding....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this instead. Don't use `e` as the var for jQuery, that's just strange. And I simplified the problem area to directly grab the elements you want instead of iterating an existing collection.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {
    var menu = $(".menu-container");
    var button = $(".menu-functions");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this)
            .scrollTop() > 150) {
            menu.addClass("f-nav");
            button.addClass("collapse-expand");
            button.addClass('collapse');
        } else {
            menu.removeClass("f-nav");
            button.removeClass("collapse");
            button.removeClass("expand");
            button.removeClass("collapse-expand");
        }
    });
    //problem area
    $('#menu-functions').click(function () {
        $('.menu-functions.collapse').addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse');
        $('.menu-functions.expand').addClass('collapse').removeClass('expand');
    });
});
```

Or this should work as well:

```
        //problem area
        $('#menu-functions').click(function () {
            $('.menu-functions.collapse, .menu-functions.expand').toggleClass('expand collapse');
        });
```

Comment: Uuum... This code contains syntax errors. Look at this `.removeClass('expand')`...

Comment: @Charlie maybe I haven't had enough coffee...I don't see it. What's the problem?

Comment: oh, removing the whitespace before the `.` and putting it in the above line fixed it! But still the class of the button does not change...

Comment: Oh weird...I'll put that on one line in the answer

Comment: @Charlie edited out the whitespace JIC, and added an alternate solution

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly! Now what I need is the second part of the question: clicking this button to actually do something, I'll add a jsfiddle in a minute.

Comment: @Charlie -- im not exactly clear on what you want to do, but I added the event handlers into [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdhnh7L/1/). Just add your code to animate stuff into the spots with the commented out lines

Comment: For the first condition, I just want to move the entire menu out of the viewport, out of the user's sight by moving it through the `Y axis` from bottom to top so that the bottom blue line and the button remain visible. I want to animate the movement itself. For the second condition it's vice-versa. When the menu is hidden just move it from top to bottom and show it as it was in the first place. If you still can't understand me I guess I'll accept this as an answer and try to find out the solution myself...